# Suppose that $(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers. Then $(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ is also a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: limits, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences, triangle-inequality

Suppose that $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers. Then $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is also a Cauchy sequence.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $a_{n}$ converges, let' say, to $L$, thus for every $\epsilon/2 > 0$ there exists a natural $N\geq 1$ such that $|a_{n} - L| \leq \epsilon/2$.

Assuming that $n,m\geq N$, the application of the triangle inequality results into
\begin{align*}
|a_{n} - a_{m}| = |(a_{n} - L) - (a_{m} - L)| \leq |a_{n} - L| + |a_{m} - L| \leq \epsilon
\end{align*}

Consequently, $a_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequences, just as desired.

Can someone double-check my solution?

Comment: I think you meant to write $|a_n - L| \le \epsilon/2$ in your first sentence, but otherwise it looks good.

Comment: Looks good. Is there a particular part that you're unsure about? By the way: you'll probably want to switch your opening line to say "for every $\epsilon>0$ there is ... such that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon/2$. Edit: @angryavian beat me to it.

Comment: +1 nice one! Actually, the converse holds too if you are working in a complete metric (like $\mathbb R$)

Comment: Your solution is fine